# Counting graceful paths

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics

How can one count the number of graceful labelings of a path graph?

Comment: in the fifth talk in this list it is conjectured order $\log(n)\log(n−1)\dots \log(2)$ http://facstaff.unca.edu/pbahls/GGGstuff/2008/FinalPresentationAbstracts.pdf

Comment: Nice, thanks. I guess I had thought there would be a closed formula!

Answer (score 2):

An efficient algorithm is described in [a paper by Michael Adamaszek](http://arXiv.com/pdf/math/0608513v1) which is powerful enough to count the number of graceful labelings of paths up to length 40.  It concludes: "It also remains an open question to find an exponential upper bound on [the number of graceful labelings of paths of length n]"

Comment: by the same author: http://oeis.org/A006967